# JMX monitoring/statistics in Akka application

Tags: akka, jmx, typesafe, akka-cluster, typesafe-console

Are there any built in JMX exposed monitoring/statistics that can be enabled in Akka (Java), besides the Cluster MBean? I have looked at Typesafe Console, but since it requires a license to be used with collecting data from multiple nodes, I was hoping to be able to achieve the same with plain JMX. I have checked the Akka documentation without any luck on this topic.

Comment: could you please have a look at this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48395416/3301316

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - the Cluster JMX support is it.

There are a couple of projects aimed at collecting data from Akka.  Both are at very early stages at this point but the code could be a starting point for you.

- Eigengo Monitor - http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2013/11/01/monitoring-akka/
- Kamon - http://kamon.io/

Both are using AspectJ to get the data out of Akka.

Typesafe Console [is free](http://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe_console_-_now_free_for_developers) to use in non-Production environments, if that works for you.

Comment: I read somewhere that Typesafe Console with support for collecting data from multiple nodes required the commercial license?

Comment: No, but there are other restrictions (see details: http://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe_console_-_now_free_for_developers)

Comment: In that case, do you have any examples of how to set up an Akka application on multiple nodes to send tracing data to the same atmos collector? Or how to use the console with multiple atmos instances? I have not found any configuration parameters that does this.

Comment: Here's where I read about the license requirement btw: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/typesafe-console/NwkumCuOzDA

Comment: No - I would ask about it on the typesafe-console Google group.

Comment: Seems like one actually does need the subscription edition to to cluster collection: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/typesafe-console/Wy_c_bVJhZY

Comment: Ya, I saw your posting to the list.  Sorry about that.  I misinterpreted the docs.  I should have pointed you to the list earlier :)

Comment: Note that Typesafe Console is now in the End-of-Life process: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/typesafe-console/MoGhs21U3IA

Comment: @sourcedelica....how to implement jmx console for akka cluster project ? could you help on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48395416/3301316

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/pull/258). I did a pull request with the necessary functionality to [Kamon](http://kamon.io).
After the release of this version (after 0.5.1), all you will need to do to make jmx work - you need to add the module `kamon-jmx` to project and activate it autostart on configuration.