# Information and management of the akka cluster using JMX console

Tags: scala, akka, jmx, akka-cluster

I am working on a project based on akka cluster, where I got to implement `JMX console` to the manage akka clusters.

When I was looking at the [akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.7/cluster-usage.html?language=scala#jmx) I got a very minimal information.

Then I tried looking at Java VisualVM, found an option to add new jmx connection like below, then what should be the connection url there ? I tried localhost:8080 but unsuccessful .

[image]

What should be configured else to get the JMX console to my akka cluster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `application.conf` for the node(s) that you want to monitor, configure the following:

```
akka.cluster.jmx.enabled = on
```

Start that node with the following JVM system properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

With the above configuration, enter `<host of the node>:9999` in the VisualVM "Connection:" prompt. Once you're connected to the node via VisualVM, look for the `akka.Cluster` JMX MBeans.

Note that this setup disables security. See the [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: can you help me how to connect remote VisualVM to AWS ec2 instance ?